# Как получить возможность редактировать css код со встроенного скрипта

Tags: javascript, html, css

есть код, для вставки на сайт

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <script src='https://salebot.pro/js/salebot_tilda.js'></script>
    <div class='salebot_tilda_block'></div>
    <script>
      SalebotTildaIntegration.init({
        project_id:85640,
        guid:'fab1362bb43349377d0d65764e859417'
      })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

я хотел бы видоизменить input и кнопку
возможно ли это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Один из наиболее простых и правильных способов - повышение специфичности селектора. Специфичность селектора рассчитывается следующим образом:

1. подсчитайте количество селекторов ID в селекторе (= a)
2. подсчитать количество селекторов классов, селекторов атрибутов и
   псевдоклассов в селекторе (= b)
3. подсчитать количество селекторов типов и псевдоэлементов в селекторе
   (= c)
4. игнорировать универсальный селектор

Селекторы внутри псевдокласса

```
отрицания учитываются как любые другие, но само отрицание не
считается псевдоклассом.
```

Конкатенация трех чисел abc (в системе счисления с большим основанием) дает специфичность.

Примеры с возрастающе специфичностью:

```
* /* a=0 b=0 c=0 -> специфичность = 0 */
LI /* a=0 b=0 c=1 -> специфичность = 1 */
UL LI /* a=0 b=0 c=2 -> специфичность = 2 */
UL OL+LI /* a=0 b=0 c=3 -> специфичность = 3 */
H1 + *[REL=up] /* a=0 b=1 c=1 -> специфичность = 11 */
UL OL LI.red /* a=0 b=1 c=3 -> специфичность = 13 */
LI.red.level /* ​​a=0 b=2 c=1 -> специфичность = 21 */
#x34y /* a=1 b=0 c=0 -> специфичность = 100 */
#s12:not(FOO) /* a=1 b=0 c=1 -> специфичность = 101 */
```

Исходя из вышеописанного есть такого рода решение:

```css
html body .sb_block .sb_btn{
  border-radius: 50%;
}

html body .sb_block #user-data-form
.justify-content-center .wh-form-field
.form-control,
html body .sb_block #user-data-form 
.justify-content-center .wh-form-field 
.input-phone-wrapper
div.select-mask
{
  background: #14a7d5;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <script src='https://salebot.pro/js/salebot_tilda.js'></script>
    <div class='salebot_tilda_block'></div>
    <script>
      SalebotTildaIntegration.init({
        project_id:85640,
        guid:'fab1362bb43349377d0d65764e859417'
      })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Другой более сложный способ - непосредственно воздействовать на стили. Сложен он прежде всего тем что нужно будет учитывать  каскадность практически вслепую, хотя позволяет добавлять стили абсолютно любого характера, например такие как :hover

Пример чтение всех подключенных к документу списков стилей

```
function getStyleSheet(unique_title) {
  for (const sheet of document.styleSheets) {
    if (sheet.title === unique_title) {
      return sheet;
    }
  }
}
```

Пример вставки правила:

```
 myStyle.insertRule('#blanc { color: white }', 0);
```

Так же на MDN можно найти примеры по другим методам например [deleteRule()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule)